# Problem with redirection selected path to different domain

Tags: .htaccess

I have this rules inside my .htaccess file what I want to obtain is to redirects all 
request that don't match **secure.x.com/en/account?x=1** to **x.com/en/account?x=1** and all request like **secure.x.com/en/account/xxxx** shouldn't be redirected.

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} secure.x.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^[a-z-]{2,8}/account [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://x.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule !\.(css|gif|htm|html|ico|jpg|js|pdf|php|png|swf|txt|xml)$ index.php
```

This rule works fine for url like 
secure.x.com/en/noaccount => redirect to x.com/en/noaccount

But not for request like
secure.x.com/en/account

What is the problem with that rule?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my problem. I don't know if this is optimal solution but it works.

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [S=3]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} local.secure.x.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ![a-z]{2,8}/account [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://local.x.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule !\.(css|gif|htm|html|ico|jpg|js|pdf|php|png|swf|txt|xml)$ index.php
```

If someone have better idea let me know. tnx.